# Using multiple CPU cores in R+ggplot2+gganimate

Tags: r, performance, parallel-processing, gganimate, cpu-cores

I have an 8-Core Intel i7 CPU, but running `anim_save` (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gganimate/versions/1.0.6/topics/anim_save) to save a `ggplot2`+`gganimate` object (https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate) to .gif is taking much longer than anticipated. Is it possible to use more than one of my CPU cores (I have 3.8 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i7) with `anim_save` (or to speed it up in some other way)?

Comment: Not yet ... https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/78 (found by starting with https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/search?q=cores&type=Issues)

Comment: Ah, good find. Thanks!